# Load MacBook Air back-up on MacBook 2017

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, backup, time-machine

I've recently purchased a MacBook 12' 2017 and would like to restore it with a TimeMachine back-up of my previous MacBook Air 13' 2014. When I try to do that from the recovery mode, an error message says something about the two models not being compatible. I wonder if this is indeed the case and if there is a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't restore as a backup, use [Migration Assistant](https://support.apple.com/HT204350) during initial setup at first boot.

If you set the machine up first & try to Migrate later, you'll end up with two users & then have to try merging them manually, which is not a lot of fun.